# Python 3 Tkinter: How do you listen to user inputs when the window is not in focus?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a python 3 program with tkinter that will listen to my keyboard input even while the window is not "focused," as in I would have a separate window open, say a browser and press the tab key, which would then put the window into focus. Is there any way that I could go about doing this?

Comment: Which operating system?  You can do this in Windows by using global hooks.

Comment: I would love for a solution that works on any os, but chrome os is also good.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter has no support for this. Tkinter can only respond to events when it has focus.